# Nodejs Heroku Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, heroku

- I have tried number of "Error R10" Solutions, but it doesn't solve the problem for a simple Hello World like Nodejs app with server.js, package.json, index.html and node_module
- Hereby adding server.js, package.json and error log
- Currently trying this app on free heroku acount
- Is it necessary to upload nodejs app  on github to host it on heroku

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = 3000;

var app = express();

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
// Body Parser MW
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {   
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));   
} else {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
}

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index.html");
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Server started ..!");
});
```

package.json

```
{
      "name": "es1",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "eS",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
        "express": "^4.14.0"
      }
    }
```

### Attaching heroku logs:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4XtAe7mRM6UVllTQWh1dmplZk0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of port as follows:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```